# how to create and export react components like ComponentA.ComponentB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

this really sound like a simple thing to know but I couldn't find any articles/resources so asking here.

how can I create components like Form.Input, Form.Select and use as follows -

```
import Form from '../Form';
...
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  ...
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Input />
      <Form.Select />
    </Form>
  );
}
```

So I basically want to understand what `Form` component is like that it is behaving like an object with sub exports like Input as `Form.Input` and `Form.Select`.

I've seen such codes at some places. Also we use `React.Component`, don't we?
I only know to export default and named components so I can create different exports like Input and Select but can't figure out how exporting Form.Input could work ?

Answer (score 1):

The dot notation may make this seem like a *subcomponent*, but it is just another component attached to the `Form` component. Take a look at the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-brahmagupta-7v0d0?file=/src/Form.js)

Basically, you have a component `Form`:

```
export const Form = (props) => {
  const Item = ({ children }) => <p> {children} </p>;
  Form.Item = Item;
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};
```

And you can access this like:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Form } from "./Form";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item> Test </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item> Test 2 </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to your Form component before exporting :

```
import React from 'react';

const Form = ({ Input, Select, children }) => (
...
);

const Input = ({ children }) => children;
Form.Input = Input;

const Select = ({ children }) => children;
Card.Select = Select;

export default Form;
```

More info here if you want :
https://dev.to/shayanypn/buckle-with-react-sub-component-10ll

Answer (score 0):

On file Form.js

```
export default {
  Input,
  Select,
}

const Input = (props) => {
  // xyz
}

const Select = (props) => {
  // xyz
}
```